# share GCE persistent disk between 2 kubernetes deployments

Tags: php, nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to move from php:7.1-apache image to php-fpm + nginx images, here is my current php deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php
  labels:
    app: php
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: php:7.1-apache
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: php
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: php
          volumeMounts:
            - name: php-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/www
      volumes:
        - name: php-persistent-storage
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: php-phantomjs-disk
            fsType: ext4
```

How can I mount the same gcePersistentDisk in the nginx deployment file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what your'e asking about is one of the most common issues with containerized PHP apps. Sharing code/content between deployments is possible only with some PV types that support ReadWriteMany policy.

If you look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes you can see that gce disks do not allow for that.

What you can do is to use other type of persistent storage that supports RWX or move nginx and fpm into the same deployment as two separate containers (has its own pros and cons).